# Unity tweak tool: how to disable window switching shortcuts?

Tags: unity, unity-tweak-tool

I found the "unity tweak tool" the other day, and today I played around a bit ... and today I wanted to make some adaptions for the task switcher.

There is a field for windows switcher shortcuts; and I am wondering: how on earth would I *disable* shortcuts?

Example: it says
Start switcher for all Workspaces

I can now click on "" and it then says "New shortcut" ... 
but well, I dont want to set a shortcut. And I could not find a way to get it to
show "Disabled" like it does for other entries.

Any idea how that would work?

Answer (score 4):

Normally if you press the  <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key it will accept that as a `null` input and disable the shortcut.